# Hadoop-2.8.0 installation on windows 10

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a problem with hadoop on windows.

When I try to start hadoop, my first start, I type on cmd the following command : hdfs namenode -format
but only think i read is : \hadoop-2.8.0\bin\ unexpected.

I setup HADOOP_HOME and JAVA_HOME and Path environment variables and I setup some of file like following

```
\\\in etc\hadoop\core-site.xml
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>

\\\in etc\hadoop\mapred-site.xml
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:54311</value>
</property>

\\\in \etc\hadoop\hdfs-site.xml
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Hello. Question : Have you ran the hadoop-env.cmd to setup environment variables that will be used by the startup scripts and the daemons ?

Comment: no no, I used the interface that provides windows to set the environment variables

Comment: OK, so maybe have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/Hadoop2OnWindows, specially "Run c:\deploy\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd to setup environment variables that will be used by the startup scripts and the daemons." Of course "c:\deploy" is an example, so replace it with the directory of your Hadoop installation.

Comment: i don't know, it sill not working... i'm trying on ubuntu but, in that case i can't set (or i didn't find the right path) of java jdk

Comment: Ok, so you must know that Ubuntu does not come with Oracle JDK preinstalled. You will have to install it by yourself. See here : https://www.tecmint.com/install-java-on-debian-10/ and make sure to install Oracle JDK12 and not OpenJDK. At the end, if "java --version" works well, just type "which java" to know the complete path to JDK

Comment: It's seems works but when i try to start hadoop with ./start-all.sh, the console launch this exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Text

Comment: I already have java installed on my ubuntu, i can find it in /usr/lib/jvm and i find java1.8.0...